# jQuery add # to all internal links

Tags: jquery, hash, hyperlink

Can someone tell me how to add hashes to all the internal links on a page?

For example:

```
page.html > page.html#
```

Thank you,
d

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're saying you only want to add `#` to links that are to pages within the same domain, you can compare the `hostname` of `window.location` to that of the link:

```
$("a").attr("href", function(i, href) {
    if( window.location.hostname === this.hostname ) {
        return href + "#";
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can pass a function to [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) like this:

```
$("a").attr("href", function(i, href) { return href + "#"; });
```

---

Though...I'm not sure on your reasoning for this, do you want to scroll to the top of the current page?  In that case you can use [`.scrollTop()`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) with a setter, like this:

```
$("a").click(function() { $("html, body").scrollTop(0); });
```

Or [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) it:

```
$("a").click(function() { $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: 0 }, 500); });
```

Comment: I may be wrong, but by "internal links" I think OP meant links to pages within the same domain.

Comment: Hi, thank you.. i don't want scroll to top... i'm trying to avoid it... i've got a lightbox with jquery.address, when i run my jquery.address page suddenly goes to top beacause jquery.address add #, so im'm trying to give the page with url+# to avoid this beahviour

Answer (score 0):

```
$("a").each(function() {
  $this = $(this);
  $this.attr("href", $this.attr("href") + "#");
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps you could try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var attr = $('a').attr('href');
    attr = attr + '#';
    $('a').attr('href', attr);
});
```

Comment: This script will cause pain... the value of "attr" would be very unpredictable and you would set every anchor tag on the page to the same link - which cannot be right.